# TFSVC to TFS-Git with Sub Projects in Same Repo

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I'm getting ready to move my TFSVC source code over to TFS Git and I'm curious about the implications of moving my TFSVC code with multiple "sub projects" over to Git where they won't be "partitioned" in different branches like they currently are.

Right now, my TFSVC looks like this:

[image: TFS Projects]

Each project has it's own "Main" branch that is separate from the other projects. When a dev branch is created, it is branched from the corresponding "Main" for each project (i.e. "ProjectA_BugFixA" was branched from the "ProjectA" main branch). After development work is complete, a dev branch is merged back to the corresponding Main branch for the project and no other project code is impacted.

1) When I move to TFS Git, I believe a dev branch will contain the entire repo structure (Projects A, B, C, D), won't it?

2) Are there any downsides to continuing with this structure after moving to TFS Git?

3) Any potential merging issues if a developer is only working on say Project A in a development branch, but has the entire repo in that branch and will merge everything back to the "master" branch?

Thanks

Comment: Hi user2966445 any update on this issue, did you get a chance to implement the solution that Daniel suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Still working on a decision, although the mono-repo approach is probably going to end up being used due to politics.

Answer (score 0):

1) It depends on how you migrate it. If you use a tool like `git-tfs`, you can choose which your root branch should be. This would be my recommendation.

2) Yes. Although "monorepos" that contain multiple distinct applications are possible to work with, they're overall harder to work with. I would strongly recommend splitting your repo up into one repository per project.

3) Not really, but it's going to cause a cluttered commit history and generally be unpleasant.

Comment: For #2, can you elaborate on "harder to work with"? I know some of the big tech giants like Google actually use the monorepo approach for their code.

Comment: Actually I think some teams at Microsoft do as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/devops-at-microsoft/use-git-microsoft

Comment: There's a much lengthier, better written explanation than I could give here: https://medium.com/@mattklein123/monorepos-please-dont-e9a279be011b